# Creating an 8 bit grayscale bitmap

Tags: android, android-bitmap, image-compression

I am developing and Android App chat. I want to make a feature where the user picks an image from Gallery and send it to server.
But before send it to server, i want to apply some actions on it, in order to reduce the size. So i want to resize compress and turn it to GrayScale.
About the gray Scale i found the below code.

```
    private fun getGrayscale(src: Bitmap): Bitmap {

        //Custom color matrix to convert to GrayScale
        val matrix = floatArrayOf(0.3f, 0.59f, 0.11f, 0f, 0f, 0.3f, 0.59f, 0.11f, 0f, 0f, 0.3f, 0.59f, 0.11f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f)

        val dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            src.width,
            src.height,
            src.config
        )

        val canvas = Canvas(dest)
        val paint = Paint()
        val filter = ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix)
        paint.colorFilter = filter
        canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0.toFloat(), 0.toFloat(), paint)

        return dest
    }
```

But when i print the size of the image i see that the size is the same although the colors go away. 
How can i convert to grayScale and reduce the size of the image..?

Thank you

Comment: That's because you're using `src.config` (same config as the original bitmap). The closest thing you can get to 8 bit in Android is `RGB_565`

Comment: Yes...you were right my friend. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped you find the right path.